# Powershell/office365 No more licenses available for AAD_basic

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

I have a powershell script that allows us to add people to our AD. We have 200 valid Azure active directory basic licenses with 169 assigned. Now however its telling its out of licenses when there should be another 31 available

No more licenses available for: Company:AAD_BASIC

Any of you that can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that deleted users still claim the licenses that you thought you had left.

In order to reclaim these licenses, you need to reactivate them, remove their licens(es) and delete them again.

```
Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers | 
    Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName  # store in a variable for convenience
        # temporarily re-activate the deleted user so we can remove the license
        $upn | Restore-MsolUser
        # get the list of licenses for this user and remove them
        $licenses = ($upn | Get-MsolUser).licenses.AccountSkuId
        $upn | Set-MsolUserLicense -RemoveLicenses $licenses
        # remove the user again
        $upn | Remove-MsolUser -Force
    }
```